# Ghostscript stopped working

Tags: ghostscript

Any gs command will return:

> WARNING: PID lock file exists /tmp/php-system-call-queue-gs-lock/pid but is empty!

And will just close the connection, I guess that it's stuck on a queue job, is there any way to fix this or restart Ghostscript service ?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no PID in the file, then just delete it.